# PieChart with all values joined

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I'm newbie and I'm working on a dashboard. I want to show with a pie chart the total value of one dimension (100% when all the registers all selected, and change it with the other filters). I've tried it with groupAll() but it doesn't work. This code works but it shows the groups separate. How can I do this? Thanks a lot!!!

CSV

```
CausaRaiz,probabilidad,costeReparacion,costePerdidaProduccion,impacto,noDetectabilidad,criticidad,codigo,coste,duracion,recursosRequeridos
PR.CR01,2,1.3,1,1,1,2,AM.PR.01,1,2,Operarios
PR.CR02,4,2.3,3,2.5,2,20,AM.PR.02,2,3,Ingenieria
PR.CR03,4,3.3,4,3.5,4,25,AM.PR.03,3,4,Externos
PR.CR04,2,2.7,2,2,2,8,AM.PR.04,3,4,Externos
FR.CR01,3,2.9,3,2.5,3,22,AM.FR.01,4,5,Ingenieria
FR.CR02,2,2.1,2,2,2,8,AM.FR.02,4,3,Operarios
FR.CR03,1,1.7,1,1,1,1,AM.FR.03,3,5,Operarios
RF.CR01,1,1.9,2,2,3,6,AM.RF.01,3,5,Externos
RF.CR02,3,3.5,4,3.5,4,20,AM.RF.02,4,4,Ingenieria
RF.CR03,4,3.9,4,3.5,4,25,AM.RF.03,4,5,Operarios
```

Code working

```
var pieCri = dc.pieChart("#criPie")
var criDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return +d.criticidad; });
var criGroup =criDimension.group().reduceCount();
pieCri
            .width(270)
            .height(270)
            .innerRadius(20)
            .dimension(criDimension)
            .group(criGroup)
            .on('pretransition', function(chart) {
                chart.selectAll('text.pie-slice').text(function(d) {
                    return d.data.key + ' ' + dc.utils.printSingleValue((d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / (2*Math.PI) * 100) + '%';
                })
            });
pieCri.render();
```

[image: Piechart]

I can show the total percentage with a number:

```
var critTotal = ndx.groupAll().reduceSum(function(d) { return +d.criticidad; });
var numbCriPerc = dc.numberDisplay("#criPerc");    
numbCriPerc
            .group(critTotal)
            .formatNumber(d3.format(".3s"))
            .valueAccessor( function(d) { return d/critTotalValue*100; } );
```

But I prefer in a pie chart to show the difference between all the registers and the selection.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what prevented you from creating the pie chart? Any errors?

Comment: I've created the pie chart, but only with options reduceCount and reduceSum. It shows all the register joined by class and I want all classes together. Thanks!

Comment: Could you edit your question and add more detail please? Your comment sounds like the right sort of information for us to help you, but you need to expand on this and show us the code which is not working, preferably with a reproducible example like a jsfiddle. BTW groupAll() is usually not the right tool for a pie chart but I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: I add more information. Thanks Gordon!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to show a pie chart with exactly two slices: the count of items included, and the count of items excluded.

You're on the right track with using groupAll, which is great for taking a count of rows (or sum of a field) based on the current filters. There are just two parts missing:

- finding the full total with no filters applied
- putting the data in the right format for the pie chart to read it

This kind of preprocessing is really easy to do with a [fake group](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups), which will adapt as the filters change.

Here is one way to do it:

```
// takes a groupAll and produces a fake group with two key/value pairs:
// included: the total value currently filtered
// excluded: the total value currently excluded from the filter
// "includeKey" and "excludeKey" are the key names to give to the two pairs
// note: this must be constructed before any filters are applied!
function portion_group(groupAll, includeKey, excludeKey) {
  includeKey = includeKey || "included";
  excludeKey = excludeKey || "excluded";
  var total = groupAll.value();
  return {
    all: function() {
      var current = groupAll.value();
      return [
        {
            key: includeKey,
          value: current
        },
        {
            key: excludeKey,
          value: total - current
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You'll construct a groupAll to find the total under the current filters:

```
var criGroupAll = criDimension.groupAll().reduceCount();
```

And you can construct the fake group when passing it to the chart:

```
        .group(portion_group(criGroupAll))
```

Note: you must have no filters active when constructing the fake group this way, since it will grab the unfiltered total at that point.

[image: include/exclude pie]

Finally, I noticed that the way you were customizing pie chart labels, they would be shown even if the slice is empty. That looked especially bad in this example, so I fixed it like this:

```
        .on('pretransition', function(chart) {
            chart.selectAll('text.pie-slice').text(function(d) {
                return d3.select(this).text() && (d.data.key + ' ' + dc.utils.printSingleValue((d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / (2*Math.PI) * 100) + '%');
            })

        });
```

This detects whether the label text is empty because of [minAngleForLabel](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.pieChart.html#minAngleForLabel__anchor), and doesn't try to replace it in that case.

[Example fiddle based on your code](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/02t4zac3/44/).

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It works perfect. Finally I changed the code to obtain the total amount of Criticidad and it works ok too.